# Lazy Load OpenLayers Map on Dialog Display?

Tags: jquery-ui, optimization, lazy-loading, openlayers

I'm developing a site where the user will choose a point on an OpenLayers map in a dialog box (displayed using jQuery UI) which will then do something on the rest of the page based on the point chosen on the map. The user can also call up the dialog at any time to pick a new point.

I've got the map dialog and passback of lat/long working just fine, but my question comes to page load optimization. I originally had all of my map code right in my `$(document).ready()` function with my OpenLayers.js call right in the `<head>` of the page. To try and improve things a bit, I moved the map code into its own .js file and put the links (`<script>` tags) to both at the very bottom of the `<body>` tag. It seems slightly better, though I do notice the navigational elements for the map (zoom controls and such) flash briefly on the screen, I presume before the stylesheet tells them to hide. Is there any way I could force the map to only load when the dialog is about to be displayed, as I feel that a slightly delay there would be more ideal than a delay in the main interface loading (subtle as that might be)? And perhaps more importantly, would it make sense to go down that road? To me, it sounds like it would be a slightly better way of doing things, but I'm open to other opinions there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could both load OpenLayers.js library and create map in dialog's open event. That way the page will load faster and you'll skip loading OpenLayers.js if user never opens dialog.

```
var scriptAlreadyLoaded = false;

$("#dialog" ).bind("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
  if(!scriptAlreadyLoaded){
    $.getScript("/scripts/OpenLayers.js", function() {
       //Instantiate OpenLayers map when script is loaded
       //...
    });
  }
  else{
    //It's second time user opens dialog so script is already loaded
    //and map instantiated.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a slight adaptation (just putting it in my click event for my button so that I could display a "loading" dialog while I wait). Now if only it weren't so slow for the map to load! That's a problem for another day, though!

Comment: glad it helped you! consider building your own version of openlayers with only features that you use in your application. in that way you can reduce the size of openlayers library considerably. here's a guide how to do this - http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html